# Low water pressure on refrigerator water dispenser

Tags: water-pressure

I have a Whirlpool Refrigerator model ED5VHEXVB00 and right now I have a low water pressure coming out of the water dispenser. The water filter needed to be replace this month and the light just turned red so I bought one and replaced it thinking that this might have something to do with the problem.  After replacing the water filter I still have the same problem.  Water pressure is very low and is making very thin ice cubes.

Comment: If you remove the filter completely do you still have low pressure (you may need to catch the water from the filter location, rather than the dispenser). Filters, even new ones, usually reduce the pressure as they filter.

Answer (score 3):

Many times the problem you are describing comes from a saddle valve a small valve that punches a hole in the existing pipe. These valves are notorious for getting plugged and leaking. The best fix would be to install a T  And a shut off valve at the location because in a few months or years most saddle valves start leaking.